# Suppose f: R to R is differentiable and its derivative has absolute value smaller than 1 for all x in R.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f\colon\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and its derivative has absolute value smaller than $1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Is it true that $f$ is a contraction*?

*That is, that there exists $c < 1$ such that $\lvert f(x)- f(y)\rvert \leq c\lvert x- y\rvert$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: No, it is not sufficient.

Comment: Which definition of contraction is in use? That there is a $c < 1$ with $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert \leqslant c\cdot\lvert x-y\rvert$?

Comment: @DanielFischer,Yes your definition is the one I want.

Comment: @T.Bongers, can you come up with a counterexample?

Comment: $$f(x) = x- \frac{1}{2}\arctan x.$$

Comment: @user3404321 Daniel Fischer's counterexample is very nice; the problem is that the derivative can get arbitrarily close to zero, so there isn't a universal contraction constant.

Comment: (close to 1, you mean, I assume?)

Comment: Yes close to 1. I see it now . Thanks!

Comment: hyperbola branch $$ \frac{1}{2} \left(x + \sqrt {1 + x^2} \right)  $$

Comment: It is true, however, if the derivative's absolute value is bounded away from $1$ from above. Note Daniel's example has $f'\to 1$ as $x$ grows large, and so does Will's example.